# Destroy Object and Instansiate it in the middle of Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, itween

I have a character that I can drag and drop around the canvas.

If you drag it onto a square, it dissappears.

All of that works well, however I want to Instansiate a clone of that character in the middle of the canvas again once it has been destroyed.

My code to do that so far is;

```
var clone = Instantiate(gameObject, startPosition, Quaternion.identity);
iTween.ScaleTo(gameObject, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 2f);
Destroy(gameObject, 3f);
```

However the object is being cloned I think but I can't see it, and I also have no idea where it is.

Any advice?

Comment: you should be able to find it in the scene view and then be able to work out why you cant see it

Comment: You are scaling to 0, isn't it? If you scale something to 0, is so little that you can't see it!

Comment: @Lotan but I'm not scaling the clone

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks, that helps a lot.  So it turns out its not Instantiating inside the canvas, which I fixed, but now its absolutely huge.  Do you have any idea why that is? The original character is 400x400, when it gets cloned its 1000x1000

Comment: try using clone.SetParent(canvasTransform, false);

Comment: Also, you need to look into the anchoring and size delta of your new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI objects **have to** be somewhere nested under a Canvas .. if you use `Instantiate` without passing any parent the GameObject is instantiated on root level without any parent => Your UI stays invisible.

Either pass it already to [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

```c#
var clone = Instantiate(gameObject, startPosition, Quaternion.identity, parentWithinCanvas.transform);
```

directly set [`transform.parent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

```c#
clone.transform.parent = parentWithinCanvas.transform;
```

or use [`transform.SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

```c#
clone.transform.SetParent(parentWithinCanvas.transform, false);
```

where the last parameter decides whether the object should keeps its current position in the world or not.